# Given the length of two altitudes and one side , find the area of triangle.

Tags: geometry, triangles

Segments $BE$ and $CF$ are the altitudes in $\triangle ABC$.
 $E$ is on line $AC$ and $F$ is on line $AB$.
$BC = 65$, $BE = 60$ and $CF = 56$.
Find $A(\triangle ABC)/100$.

[image: figure]

By the Pythagorean theorem , $CE=25$ , and $BF= 33$.
If the length of altitude from $A$ to B$C$ can be calculated then the area of $\triangle ABC$ can be calculated since the length of $BC$ is known.
But I'm stuck here , so any hints are apreciated .

Comment: One can grind it out. Let $x=EA$ and $y=FA$. By areas, $60(x+25)=56(y+33)$. Then Pythagorean Theorem gives us another equation (or two). Solve. There is undoubtedly also a clever way.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Got it , but solving those equations would be pretty time consuming , so what's the clever way?

Comment: @AGoogler: The solution by Sawarnik qualifies!

Comment: I have a related question for you. If $m_a=12$ and $m_b=9$ are medians, and the other side is $c=10$. Then the area would be?

Comment: @Sawarnik 12 is the length of median from A to BC , right?

Comment: @AGoogler Right. $c$ is $AB$.

Comment: @Sawarnik I can do it algebraically. Using Appolonius's theorem twice ( once for each median)  and then getting value of $a$ and $b$ . Then using heron's formula area can be calculated . But this approach will take a lot of time and I'm a bit sleepy right now. Do you have any better way?

Comment: @AGoogler Yes there is a better approach. Can you see $\angle GAB$, where G is the centroid is a right angle. So the area of the $ABXY$, where X,Y the midpoints of the other sides, is 54. Now $ABC=ABXY+XYC=54+ABC/4$. Good night :)

Comment: @Sawarnik do you mean Angle $AGB$ is a right angle?

Comment: Oh yes! It follows from the inverse Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: @Sawarnik yes , got it. But what if it isn't a right angle ? Can you think of a better approach in that case?

Comment: @AGoogler You can easily prove a more general theorem $A=\frac{4}{3}m_a m_b \sin \theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle of intersection of the two medians, though I am not sure how useful this is. For example, the triangle we just described has the maximum area of any triangle with medians 12 and 9, can be a corollary of this.

Answer (score 3):

We have that $\cot C=25/60$ and $\cot B=33/56$.

Now use the area formula:
$$\text{Area}=\frac{a^2}{2(\cot B + \cot C)}$$

Thus:
$$\frac{(ABC)}{100}=\frac{65^2}{200(\frac{25}{60} + \frac{33}{56})}=\frac{13^2}{8(\frac{25}{60} + \frac{33}{56})}=\frac{13^2}{\frac{10}{3} + \frac{33}{7}}=\frac{13^2}{\frac{70+99}{21}}=21$$

Comment: I have never seen that formula before. How is this derived?

Comment: @user112790 Its not very tough, I derived it once using the sine rule and the formula $2A=bc\sin A$. Just some manipulations and you're done, although I am not sure this is the optimal way. Actually I have found this formula very useful, I don't understand why people don't know or use it.

Comment: @Sawarnik Thanks ! But why did you change the formula ? In the previous version it was something like $A=a/2(tan B + tan C)$ . Are both formulas true ( right ) ?

Comment: @AGoogler No, sorry. I just confused up with the two formulas. Now its correct :)

Comment: @AGoogler Are you able to prove the formula? I suggest you remember this, because whenever you're given two angles and a side, this formula helps a lot.

Comment: @Sawarnik I didn't try , but I'll try to prove it now. Thanks  for the tip , I'll remember it now. Also I couldn't find it on the internet , from where did you find it?

Comment: @AGoogler It was a exercise in a pre-calculus book I have. But Mathworld and Wiki do have the formula, I see now.

Comment: Very fine and clear cut solution.

Comment: It' derivation is simple. Drop a perpendicular from A on BC. (Area of triangle = 1/2 .b.h). Now use cot B and cot C to get the formula. (Derivation is mailed to you.)

Comment: @Ajay Wow, nice way!

Comment: @Sawarnik thanks for complement.

Answer (score 2):

MPA entrance 2011.
Can you tell me the answer of Q.55 from Maths 2010 of MPA.
Best of luck for 6th April.I am there too.

[image: Page 1]

[image: Page 2]

Comment: Can't type with latex.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer . I'll try to solve Q.55 . Best of luck for you too!

Comment: Thanks but what's your real name? How many were solved by you?

Comment: I'm uncomfortable giving away my real name online. Can you email me instead ? (agoogler@live.com) I've solved about 30 questions randomly . Although some of them were solved by me months ago. How many have you solved?

Comment: Are the questions available online? I would like to try them too, they have very nice questions!

Comment: @Sawarnik Here - http://mprakashacademy.co.in/XI_SampleQuestions/Papersupto2013.pdf